# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape, received ((None, 32, 32, 1) vs (None, 32, 32, 3))

Tags: conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm building an autoencoder network to detect image anomaly.

```
input_img = Input(shape =(32,32,3))
# Encoder
x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)

# Decoder
x = Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1,(3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

I got a value error:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape, received ((None, 32, 32, 1) vs (None, 32, 32, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changind this line
`decoded = Conv2D(3,(3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).